# What do green stat numbers mean in Fire Emblem: Awakening?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

As the title says, I wish to know what the green numbers in a given person's stat page mean. I am assuming it means a maxed out stat, but, in the event I'm wrong, I'd like confirmation.

Google didn't turn up anything, hence my asking here.

Answer (score 11):

When a Stat turns green, it is indeed maxed out.

The exact cap varies depending on both class and unit.

Comment: The highest cap is 30, the lowest is 20. Non-promoted units will be able to (theoretically) max out every stat to 20, but not higher. The only exception is `luck`, which is always capped at 30, regardless of the class or whether you are promoted.

Comment: @Nolonar That may have been true in other FE games, but awakening is rather different. The skill caps (even for non-promoted units) vary.

Comment: I see, well Awakening isn't yet released in my region, and the caps did not change ever since FE 6, so I assumed they kept it that way in FE 13 (Awakening). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Nolonar Yup, no biggie!

Comment: In fact, it's actually pretty important that luck can go beyond 30, because when you have a "luck x 2" skill like Armsthrift and get your luck up to 48...hoo boy.